# Не отводя взгляд(а)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно, "не отводя чего или что? Взгляд или взгляда?"

Answer (score 1):

При отрицании обычно употребляется родительный падеж: отводя взгляд - не отводя взгляда.

Answer (score 0):

Не отводя взгляд (что?) В.п.